# Matlab Simulink Error with get_param

Tags: matlab, simulink

I dont understand this error : even it is the S-function , why it works at first with " sous_systems{i_sous_system} " but when I put the path directly not ?

K>> sous_systems{i_sous_system}

ans =

F0_Model/F10_01_NOK

K>> lines = get_param(sous_systems{i_sous_system}, 'Lines')

lines =

2x1 struct array with fields:

```
Handle
Name
Parent
SrcBlock
SrcPort
DstBlock
DstPort
Points
Branch
```

K>> lines = get_param(F0_Model/F10_01_NOK , 'Lines')
Error in S-function 'F0_Model/F10_01_NOK /S-Function': S-Function
'system' does not exist

Comment: Block name should be passed as string. Try, get_param('F0_Model/F10_01_NOK' , 'Lines').

Comment: thanks Navan ! it works now

Comment: Do you have any idea about this problem ? I try to set the FontSize of a line but every time I put the number " 9" when I use get_param  for the lecture  , I get " -1 " even the DefaultBlockFontSize is not 9 !!! this happens only with 9 the other numbers it works

Comment: I do not know about the font size issue. It is possible that font does not have that size and it was only caught when setting the size.